# How to increase the font size of Tab Bar title?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Can I increase the font size of Tabbar title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible; you'd have to build your own tab bar and design the tabs yourself. And if you do, how you'll get that to work with `UITabBarController` or some other way would be a completely different question.